# Best way to extend Dockerfile to pull deps/env vars from common/shared repositories

Tags: docker

We have application repositories with common shared repos. Our application repos contain Dockerfiles and what we are trying to do is whenever common/shared repos change and depend on other libraries or env vars we want to have Dockerfiles in these common/shared repos as well. And the Dockerfile in the application repo will include them so that any deps/env changes are pulled in from the common/shared repos.
After googling for "docker include another dockerfile" I found the github issue https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/735. Which is exactly what we are looking for but this issue doesn't provide a clear solution. Is there best way to achieve this as of now? Thanks

Comment: Dockerfiles should not depend on any variables. This is against most basic Docker principle "build once, run anywhere".

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to create you own base image. In your base image goes any common code. And then other Dockerfiles refer to this image in their FROM line.

Dockerfile for base image:

```
# pick an image to work off of
FROM debian:latest

# do your common stuff here
```

Then run `docker build -t mybase:latest .`

Now in the other images you want to create, they have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mybase:latest

# do your non-common stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, but it might not cover everything you're looking for. If the common repo has a shell script that installs dependencies and sets environment variables then you can invoke the shell script while building the image, by copying the shell script to the image and running it.

Say for example, you have a file called `env_script.sh` in your common_repo that looks like like

```
    #!/bin/bash
    apt install -y libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev pkg-config
    pip install flask
    export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/local/my_"
```

then the Dockerfile of your application would use it as below:

```
    COPY ./common_repo/env_script.sh /tmp/ # Copy the shell script
    RUN /tmp/env_script.sh       # Run the shell script
    RUN rm /tmp/env_script.sh    # Remove temporary file after done
```